# How to write the pattern in regular expression matching in Pl/SQL?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I have written a substring regular expression in Oracle. I am having a problem with the correct pattern matching. The substring query first fetches the ddl of the trigger into a string and then tries to separate the table's columns from it.

**Trigger DDL**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SHIVAMG"."DVJ_CI_CURRENCY_CD_L_IU"
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON CI_CURRENCY_CD_L
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    IF (UPPER(:NEW.CURRENCY_CD) NOT LIKE 'ZZ%') THEN
      INSERT INTO JUNITUSR.CI_CURRENCY_CD_L
        (CURRENCY_CD,
         LANGUAGE_CD,
         DESCR,
         VERSION)
      SELECT :NEW.CURRENCY_CD,
             :NEW.LANGUAGE_CD,
             :NEW.DESCR,
             :NEW.VERSION
       FROM DUAL
       WHERE NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT 1
            FROM JUNITUSR.CI_CURRENCY_CD_L B
            WHERE B.CURRENCY_CD =:NEW.CURRENCY_CD AND
                  B.LANGUAGE_CD = :NEW.LANGUAGE_CD);
    END IF;
  END IF;

  IF UPDATING THEN
    IF (UPPER(:NEW.CURRENCY_CD) NOT LIKE 'ZZ%') THEN
      UPDATE JUNITUSR.CI_CURRENCY_CD_L A
        SET CURRENCY_CD     =:NEW.CURRENCY_CD,
            LANGUAGE_CD       =:NEW.LANGUAGE_CD,
            DESCR             =:NEW.DESCR ,
            VERSION           =:NEW.VERSION
        WHERE A.CURRENCY_CD = :OLD.CURRENCY_CD AND
              A.LANGUAGE_CD =:OLD.LANGUAGE_CD;
    END IF;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'ERROR: <DVJ_CI_CURRENCY_CD_L_IU> ' || SQLERRM);
END;

ALTER TRIGGER "SHIVAMG"."DVJ_CI_CURRENCY_CD_L_IU" ENABLE"
```

**Substring Query**

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR((SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR 
    (( select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER', 'DVJ_CI_CURRENCY_CD_L_IU' ) from dual), 'INSERT INTO(.*)+\)')FROM dual),'\((.*)\)') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include: 1) the results you expect, and 2) the results you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: Question is unclear. Please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct Substring query to gather the individual column names from the trigger code. It is as follows:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR((SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR((SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (( SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TRIGGER',trig_name,'CISADM') FROM dual),
'INSERT(\s|\n)+INTO[^\)]+\)',1,1,'n') FROM dual),'[\(](\s|\n|.)+[\)]')
 FROM DUAL),'(\w)+',1,counter)INTO temp_col_name FROM dual;
```